# How to solve this error, getInstance(android.content.Context) in com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics cannot be applied to My mainActivity

Tags: android, firebase

followed this blog 
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-firebase-integrate-analytics/

errors -

1. 'com.example.agthamays.firebase_001.MainActivity' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity' in AndroidManifest.xml
2. 'getInstance(android.content.Context)' in 'com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics' cannot be applied to '(com.example.agthamays.firebase_001.MainActivity)' in MainActivity

Comment: Show us more code, how are you getting the instance? Passing `this` to `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance()` should work if placed in `Activity`

Comment: Your Activity class doesn't extend an Activity, therefore it isn't a Context